# How to recode a range of values (numeric) into a factor variable?

Tags: r, dplyr, recode

I want to recode a variable that has values from 1 to 10 (numeric) into a factor variable of 5 values. I'm using the command dplyr::recode, but it is not working. I know how to do it with the cut function or case_when, but i want to know if there is a way to do it with the recode function.

I'm trying this code but is showing an error:

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(x_rec = as.factor(recode(x, '1:2' = '1',
                                  '3:4' = '2', '5:6'= '3',
                                  '7:8' = '4', '9:10' = '5')))
```

The output shows this:

```
Warning messages:
1: Problem while computing `x_rec = as.factor(...)`.
ℹ NAs introduced by coercion 
2: Problem while computing `x_rec = as.factor(...)`.
ℹ Unreplaced values treated as NA as `.x` is not compatible.
```

I tried to use drop_na(), but is not working. I also tried to use the argument ".default = NA" and ".missing = NA" but it says that is an unused argument. If someone can help me it would be great. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `recode()` will only help you if your input is a factor variable already. Use `cut()` to convert numerical values into factor levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`recode()` will only help you if your input is a factor variable already. Use `cut()` to convert numerical values into factor levels.

```r
set.seed(42)
x <- sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE)

cut(x,
    breaks = c(0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10),
    labels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
#>  [1] 1 3 1 5 5 2 1 5 1 4
#> Levels: 1 2 3 4 5
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Two easy options, using integer division or `cut`:

```
mutate(
  df, 
  x_new1 = factor((x + 1) %/% 2),
  x_new2 = ggplot2::cut_width(x, 2, center = 1, labels = FALSE)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

We may use `case_match` here

```
library(dplyr)# version >= 1.1.0
df %>%
   mutate(x_rec = factor(case_match(x, c(1, 2) ~1,
   c(3, 4) ~ 2, c(5, 6) ~ 3, c(7, 8) ~ 4, c(9, 10) ~ 5)))
```

-output

```
    x x_rec
1   7     4
2   3     2
3   8     4
4   7     4
5   2     1
6   3     2
7  10     5
8   8     4
9   6     3
10 10     5
11  9     5
12  4     2
13  9     5
14  8     4
15  7     4
16  8     4
17  1     1
18  8     4
19  1     1
20  5     3
```